# Web-to-Lead: Receiving E-mail in Inbox. how to prevent email?

Tags: web2lead

iam creating web to lead in my developer edition is working fine reciving email from end user but prevent the email from end user

please any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

edit the button remove Email template i hope this is ur help full